# Kendo grid performance issue (Kendo Grid + Angular JS + Web API)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Issue :

I am having Kendo Grid in my Angular JS html page. Kendo Grid data is coming from my remote service Web API.

Kendo grid try to download content of 38 MB in browser for each 10 records while we are doing Paging (or page load on first time) and it takes approx. 6 minutes to load data.

**What and which content it is downloading for 38 MB ?**

What i already implemented by reading/learning similar support tickets on stack overflow :

1. Implemented Server Paging true (pageSize = 10, Total records = 56000 approx.)
2. Bundling of JS and CSS
3. I tried both below options:

   scrollable: { virtual: true }
   OR 
   scrollable: { endless: true }
4. I check my stored procedure on production, it executes in less than 3 seconds for approx. 55000 records. (on production and staging both servers).
5. I check my Web API controller, it returns response in less than 4 seconds to kendo grid, and then kendo grid takes too much time to populate data.
6. I have below JS and CSS for Kendo (already implemented bundling) :

   - Kendo.all.min.js
   - kendo.bootstrap.min.css
   - kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css
   - Other needed JS and CSS for project are also loads in bundling manner.

Below are my live project pages :

HTML Page :

```
<div id="heatMapGrid" kendo-grid k-options="vm.heatMapGridOptions"></div>
```

AngularJS Controller :

```
var dataSourceHeatMapGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {

                    heatMapService.getHeatMapGrid(options.data, heatMapGridParams)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            options.success(response.data);
                            $rootScope.optioncallback = options;

                            //$scope.htmapGridCSV = [];
                            //$scope.htmapGridCSV = response.data.exportData;

                        }).catch(function (e) {
                            console.log('Error: ', e);
                            throw e;
                        });
                },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    return JSON.stringify(options);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return response.gridData;
                },
                total: function (response) {
                    return response.Total;
                },
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        TPID: { type: "number" },
                        TPName: { type: "string" },
                        EndCustomerPurchaseAmt: { type: "number" },
                        PrimaryExpirationMonth: { type: "string" },
                        AgreementID: { type: "number" },
                        TotalPurchased: { type: "number" },
                        TotalAssigned: { type: "number" },
                        OverUnder: { type: "number" },
                        VSEntPurchasedUnits: { type: "number" },
                        VSProMSDNUnits: { type: "number" },
                        VSTestProMSDNUnits: { type: "number" },
                        MSDNPlat: { type: "number" },
                        CloudPurchasedUnits: { type: "number" },
                        UnbilledOverage: { type: "number" },
                        AzurePotentialRevenue: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true
        });

vm.heatMapGridOptions = {
            columns: [
                { "title": "", template: "<a title='#=TPID#' #=isPinnedAccount==1 ? \"class='terrunpinaccount'\" : \"class='terrpinaccount'\"# ng-click='vm.pinUnpinAccount(\"#=TPID#\")'></a>" },
                { "title": "Account Name", "field": "TPName", template: "<a href='javascript:void(0);' ng-click='vm.tPIDDetails(\"#=TPID#\",\"#=TPName#\")' title='#=TPName#'><div class='DisplayTitleTPName'>#=TPName#<ul><li>AM: #=AM#, OM: #=OperatingModel#, Country: #=Country#</li><li>DevSales Lead: #=SalesLead#, SSP: #=Dev_SSP#, TSP: #=DevTSP#</li></ul></div></a>", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                {
                    "title": "PERFORMANCE AND ANNIVERSARIES", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                    columns:
                    [{
                        "title": "Renewals and True Ups", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                        columns: [{ "title": "Total Annualized Expiring", "field": "EndCustomerPurchaseAmt", format: "{0:c0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Primary Anniversary Month", "field": "PrimaryExpirationMonth", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Agreement Number", "field": "AgreementID", format: "{0:n0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "title": "EFFECTIVE LICENSE POSITIONS", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                    columns:
                    [{
                        "title": "Visual Studio Subscriptions", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                        columns: [{ "title": "Purchased", "field": "TotalPurchased", format: "{0:n0}" },
                                { "title": "Assigned", "field": "TotalAssigned", format: "{0:n0}" },
                                { "title": "Over Under", "field": "OverUnder", format: "{0:n0}" }]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Account Footprint (Active SA Licenses)", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                        columns: [{ "title": "Enterprise w/ MSDN", "field": "VSEntPurchasedUnits", format: "{0:n0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Pro w/ MSDN", "field": "VSProMSDNUnits", format: "{0:n0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Test Pro w/ MSDN", "field": "VSTestProMSDNUnits", format: "{0:n0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "MSDN Platforms", "field": "MSDNPlat", format: "{0:n0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Cloud", "field": "CloudPurchasedUnits", format: "{0:n0}" }]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Azure", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bold;" },
                        columns: [{ "title": "Unbilled Overage", "field": "UnbilledOverage", format: "{0:c0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } },
                                { "title": "Potential Revenue", "field": "AzurePotentialRevenue", headerTemplate: '<span title="Potential Revue is based on the delta of activated seats and <br/> developers deploying to Azure multiplied by the annual <br/> value of an Azure attached developer ($15k)">Potential Revenue</span>', format: "{0:c0}", headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal; overflow: visible;" } }]
                    }]
                }
            ],
            groupable: false,
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            //pageable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: [10, 20, 50],

            },
            columnMenu: true,
            scrollable: false
            //filterable: true
        };

$("#heatMapGrid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSourceHeatMapGrid);
```

AngularJS Service :

```
services.getHeatMapGrid = function (command, heatMapGridParams) {
            var data = {
                page: command.page,
                pageSize: command.pageSize,
                skip: command.skip,
                take: command.take,
                alias: heatMapGridParams.alias,
                hasDevTest: heatMapGridParams.hasDevTest,
                hasDevTestLabs: heatMapGridParams.hasDevTestLabs,
                hasXamarin: heatMapGridParams.hasXamarin,
                devOpsMSShopFlag: heatMapGridParams.devOpsMSShopFlag,
                devOpsOSSThirdPartyShopsFlag: heatMapGridParams.devOpsOSSThirdPartyShopsFlag,
                intelligentAppsFlag: heatMapGridParams.intelligentAppsFlag,
                paaSServicesFlag: heatMapGridParams.paaSServicesFlag,
                enterpriseStepUpFlag: heatMapGridParams.enterpriseStepUpFlag,
                devsLearningAzureFlag: heatMapGridParams.devsLearningAzureFlag,
                devOpsAcceleratorEligibleFlag: heatMapGridParams.devOpsAcceleratorEligibleFlag,
                overAssignedFlag: heatMapGridParams.overAssignedFlag,
                lowAssignmentsFlag: heatMapGridParams.lowAssignmentsFlag,
                hasCloudSubscriptionFlag: heatMapGridParams.hasCloudSubscriptionFlag,
                hasUnbilledOverageFlag: heatMapGridParams.hasUnbilledOverageFlag,
                hasDevTestOppty: heatMapGridParams.hasDevTestOppty,
                areaID: heatMapGridParams.areaID,
                countryID: heatMapGridParams.countryID,
                segmentID: heatMapGridParams.segmentID,
                subsegmentID: heatMapGridParams.subsegmentID,
                salesUnitID: heatMapGridParams.salesUnitID,
                agreementRenewalOrTrueupID: heatMapGridParams.agreementRenewalOrTrueupID,
                aM: heatMapGridParams.aM,
                industry: heatMapGridParams.industry,
                hasAppServOppty: heatMapGridParams.hasAppServOppty,
                hasDotNetDeveloperFlag: heatMapGridParams.hasDotNetDeveloperFlag,
                paaSReadyFlag: heatMapGridParams.paaSReadyFlag,
                startMonth: heatMapGridParams.startMonth,
                endMonth: heatMapGridParams.endMonth
            };
            return $http({ method: 'GET', url: config.apiUrl + 'Account/HeatMapGrid/', params: data });
        };
```

Web API :

```
[HttpGet]
    public heatMapGridAndExport HeatMapGrid([FromUri]HeatMapGridModel model)
    {
        ListView listView = new ListView();

        List<getHeatMapDataGlobalFilter_Result> listGridDataForTotalCount = new List<getHeatMapDataGlobalFilter_Result>();
        listGridDataForTotalCount = listView.GetListViewGridData(model.alias, model.hasDevTest, model.hasDevTestLabs, model.hasXamarin, model.devOpsMSShopFlag, model.devOpsOSSThirdPartyShopsFlag, model.intelligentAppsFlag, model.paaSServicesFlag, model.enterpriseStepUpFlag, model.devsLearningAzureFlag, model.devOpsAcceleratorEligibleFlag, model.overAssignedFlag, model.lowAssignmentsFlag, model.hasCloudSubscriptionFlag, model.hasUnbilledOverageFlag, model.hasDevTestOppty, model.areaID, model.countryID, model.segmentID, model.subsegmentID, model.salesUnitID, model.agreementRenewalOrTrueupID, model.aM, model.industry, model.hasAppServOppty, model.hasDotNetDeveloperFlag, model.paaSReadyFlag, model.startMonth, model.endMonth);

        List<getHeatMapDataGlobalFilter_Result> listGridData = new List<getHeatMapDataGlobalFilter_Result>();
        listGridData = listGridDataForTotalCount.Skip(model.skip).Take(model.take).OrderByDescending(c => c.EndCustomerPurchaseAmt).ToList();

                    //List<heatMapExport> listExportData = new List<heatMapExport>();
        //listExportData = listGridDataForTotalCount.Select(c => new heatMapExport()
        //{
        //    TPName = c.TPName,
        //    TPID = c.TPID,
        //    OperatingModel = c.OperatingModel,
        //    Area = c.Area,
        //    Country = c.Country,
        //    CreditedRegion = c.CreditedRegion,
        //    CreditedDistrict = c.CreditedDistrict,
        //    Segment = c.Segment,
        //    ATUManager = c.ATUManager,
        //    Dev_SSP = c.Dev_SSP,
        //    AM = c.AM,
        //    Industry = c.Industry,
        //    ATSName = c.ATSName,
        //    AssignedPect = string.Format("{0:p0}", c.AssignedPect),
        //    ActivatedPect = string.Format("{0:p0}", c.ActivatedPect),
        //    AzureActivated = Convert.ToString(c.AzureActivated),
        //    EndCustomerPurchaseAmt = string.Format("{0:c0}", c.EndCustomerPurchaseAmt),
        //    PrimaryExpirationMonth = Convert.ToString(c.PrimaryExpirationMonth),
        //    AgreementID = Convert.ToString(c.AgreementID),
        //    TotalPurchased = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.TotalPurchased),
        //    TotalAssigned = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.TotalAssigned),
        //    OverUnder = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.OverUnder),
        //    VSEntPurchasedUnits = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.VSEntPurchasedUnits),
        //    VSProMSDNUnits = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.VSProMSDNUnits),
        //    VSTestProMSDNUnits = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.VSTestProMSDNUnits),
        //    MSDNPlat = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.MSDNPlat),
        //    CloudPurchasedUnits = string.Format("{0:n0}", c.CloudPurchasedUnits),
        //    UnbilledOverage = string.Format("{0:c0}", c.UnbilledOverage),
        //    AzurePotentialRevenue = string.Format("{0:c0}", c.AzurePotentialRevenue)
        //}).ToList();
        var heatMapData = new heatMapGridAndExport
        {
            gridData = listGridData,
            //exportData = listExportData,
            Total = listGridDataForTotalCount.Count()
        };
        return heatMapData;
    }
```

My Environment :

1. Version Telerik Control -  Kendo UI v2017.2.621
2. Operating System Development machine - Windows 10 Enterprise (8 GB RAM, Intel Core i7 Processor, 64 bit) (Client OS)
3. Browser - Google Chrome, Version 65.0.3325.181
4. .NET Framework - Version 4.6.1
5. Visual Studio - Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 (Update 3)
6. Coding Language - C#

Here is my browser screen shot for production server :

[image: Here is my production server kendo grid, which takes almost 12 minutes to populate data in kendo grid, and you can see TTFB (Time To First Byte. This timing includes 1 round trip of latency and the time the server took to prepare the response) for this request is 3.26 seconds]

Here is the another screenshot when i am clicking on 2nd page, it again download 38 mb content and it takes approx. 6 minutes. (server paging = true and pageSize = 10)

[image]

Code Debugging screenshots:

[image]

What i am doing wrong? Can any one please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you disable the line where you attach the ~56K rows of export data to the WebAPI response and see how it performs? (answer below, for clarity). I suspect that's your problem

Comment: @JoeGlover, Thanks for reply. but I already tried by commenting that whole export functionality, but there is no effect on time or content it downloads. i.e Nothing improves by removing export functionality. Any other help appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: It would help to see exactly what is in that 38Mb, either by break-pointing your WebAPI just before it returns it's response (from your previous comment I'm guessing `heatMapData.gridData` must therefore contain the entire data set), or inspecting the JSON as it appears on the wire. You should be able to drill into that in the Chrome dev tools, or alternatively use an external tool like Fiddler, Wireshark etc.

Comment: Another thing to try would be the ordering of your Linq method calls. I'm amending my original answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @JoeGlover previously i was also thinking the same, but then i checked `heatMapData.gridData` in WebAPI response by debugging the code and also checked in fiddler, but at both the times it contains only 10 records not whole data set (as i used skip and take)
And for ordering, i checked by swap ordering clause before skip/take but no effect and also tried by removing ordering, but no luck at both the times. Any other help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: OK, that's disappointing. If everything looks okay just before the WebAPI returns it's response, then the answer must lie in the fiddler trace. Is something massive getting attached perhaps in the headers? It must be something like that if your data payload is okay. For comparison, I have a grid here which typically requests 11.4Kb / 10 rows, 174Kb / 100 rows, 3Mb / 1000 rows. Does fiddler show message sizes around 38Mb still?

Comment: @JoeGlover, i checked on fiddler, YES it is showing size of 38MB after for the response. And final response object have three things in it :
1. gridData = 10 records
2. exportData = 55000 records
3. Total = 55000 (Count = int number)
I have attached screenshot for my dev code debugging. can you please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you disable the line where you attach the ~56K rows of export data to the WebAPI response and see how it performs? I suspect that's your problem

```
    var heatMapData = new heatMapGridAndExport
    {
        gridData = listGridData,
        //exportData = listExportData,  //perhaps make conditional, for export only?
        Total = listGridDataForTotalCount.Count()
    };
    return heatMapData;
```

Edit: Since that doesn't seem to have fixed your problem, can you please try re-ordering the Linq method calls like this, as the behaviour you're getting implies the entire result set is coming back?

```
listGridData =
    listGridDataForTotalCount.OrderByDescending(c => c.EndCustomerPurchaseAmt)
        .Skip(model.skip).Take(model.take).ToList();
```

I don't know for certain, but I wonder if having the `OrderByDescending` last forces Linq to go back to the entire resultset and that's what you end up getting from the `ToList`?

Comment: Some additional context and description would improve this answer.

Comment: @JoeGlover, I tried by re-ordering the Linq method calls as you say, but no luck.

Comment: @KevinO, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @JoeGlover, It is unexpected that previously i remove export but no effect on performance (and content) but now i again tried the same and i found that  Export data causing the issue. I removed it and gzip encoding to get it even more faster. Thank you

Comment: Not that unexpected, it happens to us all from time to time! Thanks for letting me know the problem is solved.